# Search a word in a given paragraph

Tags: algorithm

You are given a paragraph in which the length of all the words in a line has following properties:

- **Odd** position words are in **increasing** order of their length.
- **Even** position words are in **decreasing** order of their length.

You are given a word, and have to write a code to search it in the given paragraph and return the line number.

Comment: How is the paragraph given? as a `char[]`/`String` or as a list of words/lines? [and each word/line is a `char`/`String`]

Comment: @mekici It was recently asked in an interview.

Comment: are they guaranteed to be strictly increasing/decreasing?

Answer (score 7):

If each line is given by a list of words, it is actually two sorted sublists:

(1) list of odd words: sorted increasinly by length

(2) list of even words: sorted decreasingly by length

Use a binary search on both lists, with a comparator accordding to : `word.length()`

Once you find a match [the word you are looking for and the word in the list you are currently searching] is in the same length: check if it is the same word.

repeat for each line.

**Complexity** [for each line]: `O(logn * |S|)` where `|S|` is the size of your word and `n` is the number of words in a line.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be no requirements to the run-time complexetity - so why not just implement a linear search? Maybe that odd/even thing was just added to confuse you! Keep it simple ;)

Comment: In an interview question, the answer is ***never*** "linear search".

Comment: Interviews Qs may have some noise to confuse you. Your job is then to extract the relevant pieces.

Comment: In my answer I was not trying to be rude. I just re-read the Q before jumping into a complex solution! But sure I acknowledge above solution too! Cheers :)

Comment: But there's a difference between a *simple* solution and a *naive* solution. And an interviewer is never going to be looking for the answer which requires no thought or insight. Re "extracting relevant pieces", when it comes to search questions, it doesn't get much more relevant than the fact that your set is sorted ;)